# Identify individual element of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular, but I know Jquery. I have done something like below :
I am getting the following data from the controller  :

```
 var data = [
{
  id : 0,
  name : 'Nemo', 
  path : 'img/fishBlow.jpg',
  cover : 'img/cover.jpg',
  flip : false
}, ... etc
```

In my view I want to access each of the individual card on click event;
How can I identify a particular card ? 
In jquery I can find parent and do rest of the sutffs....

```
  <div class='container' data-ng-controller="InitCtrl">
             <h2>{{Message}}</h2>

        <div class="wrapper"  data-ng-repeat = "card in suffle()" >
              <div class="card flipped" id={{card.id}}>
                <figure class="front">
                  <img ng-src="{{card.path}}" />

                </figure>
                <figure class="back">
                    <img ng-src="{{card.cover}}" />
                </figure>
              </div>

        </div>


       </div>
```

Comment: Just use `ng-click="myFunction(card)"`? :v

Comment: angular will remember all the card objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to angular I am not giving you the most technical details but a high level idea:

Inside your `ng-repeat` (AKA on the `div.wrapper`) you will have access to current `card` of the iteration. Thanks to that, you can do something like `{{card.id}}` or `{{card.path}}`. That means you have access to the `card` object to do what you want to do there. That also means you can pass that concrete card back to the controller via click like:

`<button ng-click="selectCard(card)">Select</button>`

Notice the parameter of the function, it is the concrete card of that iteration. Doing that, you can access the concrete card on a click.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/bc4cVNmgrA4Vdv4kcoTF?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help. yes I am new to angular. I have seen most of the beginner resources on youtube. Can you please suggest some books that can help me learn angular. 
-Thanks

Comment: I like this one: http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book?tag=dp/masteringwebwithangularjs-abr1/0913

Comment: sorry to bother you jesus but I would like to ask one quick question to you. In following code the suffle() function suffles the list of object everytime page is reloaded so that I can display random cards each time.
`<div class="wrapper"  data-ng-repeat = "card in suffle()" >`
ng-click:
I am doing click event on each of the card in list. The click event has to rotate that individual card on click. But instead it rotates random cards from the list.
`<div class="card" id={{card.id}} data-ng-class= "[card.flip]" data-ng-click  = "flip(card)">'
`card in CardList` solves the problem.

Comment: I don't follow at all. Comments are really bad for this. Create a new question or join angular's IRC channel.